# Handwritten instead of printed

Tags: discussion

I'm having a hard time understanding hand-written Japanese. I don't mean just elaborate calligraphy, but also normal stuff. Also writing natural looking Japanese is a problem.

Although I could ask someone about a concrete Kanji, I'd like to improve my ability to be able to deal with it. Apparently, it's an issue for most learners of Japanese. Maybe the Chinese don't have this problem, since they build from a different base.

Are there resources where I could maybe read the hand-written parallel to the typed version? I don't need just individual Kanji, but full texts, notes, faxes (seem to be quite common still in Japan still).

Comment: This is probably more of a meta question.

Comment: Agree that it's more of a meta question, but a good basic starting alternative is to install "handwriting" fonts onto your machine and use them to write out sentences and note the differences and similarities to each other between the "handwritten" style and the "typed" style

Comment: I would say practicing writing yourself is the best way to go. If you write *a lot* by hand, and you do it *correctly* (proper stroke order), you will eventually figure out the patterns and recognize them in other writing too.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18782/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34497/5010

Comment: Maybe you can check [these fonts](https://www.freejapanesefont.com/category/semi-cursive-script/) out?

Comment: @Tommy: yes, nice tip, that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your actual language ability plays an important part in text recognition. Also, there is no satisfactory substitute apart from actually reading lots of handwritten notes and gaining experience.

Without knowing what your comprehension level is at, I suggest downloading some fonts and tweaking your web browser or pasting text in a word processor to the different font.

Recognising handwriting is part of a bigger skill of accommodating for shape variations in *kanji*. For minimum comprehension skills, stick to Japanese-only shapes:

**Beginner:**

- Textbook fonts (教科書体)

  > [image]
  >
  > [DFP教科書体](https://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=1701)
- [Regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) fonts (楷書体)

  > [image]
  >
  > [DF Kaisho](https://www.fonts.com/font/dynacomware/df-kaku-pop-japanese/df-kaisho-complete-family-pack)

**Intermediate:**

- [Semi-cursive/running script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-cursive_script) fonts (行書体)

  > [image]
  >
  > [DFP GyoSho](https://www.dynacw.com/en/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=196)

Google can point you to some places where you can find similar fonts to the above for free, but they have strict usage terms so I won't link them directly here.

---

If these are too standard, or you've reached a skill cap, you can try for fonts designed for outside of the Japanese region. Most modern East Asian fonts will include *kana* regardless of language, so you should be fine. Note that Chinese/Taiwanese, Japanese, and Korean handwriting habits are actually shared to a very large degree, despite national policies encouraging writing and printing in their different respective "standard" ways, so there is no harm in widening your tolerance of *kanji* shapes.

*Using the following are not recommended for beginners, if you're still grasping the basics of kanji.*

**Intermediate:**

- Korean and Chinese printed standards (e.g. from [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/))

  > [image]
  >
  > Noto Serif CJK KR

  *The Korean standard is **very** useful for higher levels of kanji recognition, as it unifies some of the component shape inconsistencies in [Jōyō kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji), and is also a step towards reading pre-War materials in [kyūjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai)*.
- [Imitation Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_Song) (宋朝体・仿宋体)

  > [image]
  >
  > [文悅古體仿宋](https://wytype.com/typeface/WyueGutiFangsong)

  *This is a commonly used Chinese printed shape standard which looks somewhat like stiff handwriting.*
- Hard-tipped pen fonts

  > [image]
  >
  > 方正硬筆楷書

**Advanced:**

- Extremely conservative printed fonts (明朝体) (e.g. [I.Ming](https://github.com/ichitenfont/I.Ming/tree/master/5.10))

  > [image]
  >
  > I. Ming

  *Actively introduces shape features from [small seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) into the printing aesthetic.*
- Pseudo-*kyūjitai* fonts (e.g. [Asebi Minchō](https://metasta.github.io/asebi/))

  > [image]
  >
  > Asebi Minchō

  *Warning: due to the complications of kyūjitai vs. [shinjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai) (see [同音の漢字による書きかえ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E9%9F%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88)), the shapes produced by these fonts may be misleading.*

Comment: @drooze What is the name of the hard-tipped pen font that you mention and show above?

Comment: @kandyman it is called 方正硬筆楷書, by a notable foundry 方正. It’s not useful for Japanese unfortunately, as I don’t think it supports kana (and therefore unlikely to support Shinjitai). There should be Japanese equivalents, but I’m not familiar enough with Japanese typography to know them.